# PHP for loop not working

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for loop to go through an array I get from a web service that are paths to images, that I want to insert into  and  tags and print as much as there are in the array. The problem is the that for loop doesn't work as it is supposed to. It always prints out only one div with the correct image, and it is supposed to print out 4 of them. When I echo format 4 times by myself without using a loop, everything is fine.

Here is the code:

```
$format ='';

if(count($curl_odgovor_decoded) > 0)
        {
            $format ='';

            for ($i=1; $i < count($curl_odgovor_decoded); $i++) { 
                if($curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika'.$i] != null)
                {
                    $format.='<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                    <a href="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika'.$i].'" title="slika'.$i.'" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-customer" src="">
                    </a></div>';

                }

            }
echo $format;
        }
        else
        {
            $format = ' <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <p>Za ovaj oglas jos uvek nisu postavljene fotografije smestaja</p>
            </div>';

            echo $format;
        }
```

If I do this it works fine(and I know that this is plain stupid, but I had to try it to test if something else was wrong and not the for loop):

```
echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika1'].'" title="slika1" >
        <img class="img-responsive img-customer" src="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika1'].'">
        </a></div>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika2'].'" title="slika2" >
        <img class="img-responsive img-customer" src="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika2'].'">
        </a></div>';    
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika3'].'" title="slika3" >
        <img class="img-responsive img-customer" src="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika3'].'">
        </a></div>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <a href="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika4'].'" title="slika4" >
        <img class="img-responsive img-customer" src="'.$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]['slika4'].'">
        </a></div>';
```

I cannot find the problem with the for loop, why would it print out just one div with the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since apparently everything is in `$curl_odgovor_decoded[0]`, `count($curl_odgovor_decoded)` returns exactly `1`, therefore it only loops once. It seems more sensible to use a foreach loop here:

```
foreach ($curl_odgovor_decoded[0] as $key => $slika) {
    '... <a href="' . $slika . '" title="' . $key . '" ...';
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! :)
So the problem was that it was an array within an array and I only counted for the first array which has only one element. Got it.